# What is the cheapest way to get the Showroom award in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I want to get the Showroom platinum award in GTA Online.  I'm wondering what is the cheapest way to do so.  Which cars, buildings, and mods do I need to buy and how much is the minimum price of this award?

Edit: I'm specifically playing on Xbox 360.  But I'd be willing to try answers for any system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just finished The Showroom award and this was the list I came up with.

**TLDR:** If you just order 30 Elegy RH8s and can store them all, you should get the award.

**Properties**
You need three properties with 10 car garages to store all 30 cars.  The three cheapest properties with 10 car garages are:

- 1623 South Shambles St - Garage - 105,000
- 1337 Exceptionalist Way - Garage - 112,500
- Unit 76 Greenwich Parkway - Garage - 120,000

Property total just garages: 337,500

I'm going to assume that someone would want at least one high rise apartment in order to do Heists and other things.  So instead of the most expensive garage, you'd buy the cheapest 10 car apartment:

- 1623 South Shambles St - Garage - 105,000
- 1337 Exceptionalist Way - Garage - 112,500
- Del Perro Heights, Apt 7 - Apartment - 200,000

Property with apartment: 417,500

**Cars**
You need 30 cars total and I see 3 different sources for getting these cars.

One source is getting Elegy RH8s which are free on consoles if you sign up for the social club.  Plus, they already count as "modded" which will help in the next section.  Unfortunately, if you are on PC, they cost 95,000 and the total will jump up to 2,850,000.

The other two options are stealing cars or buying Karin Rebels.

- [Elegy RH8](http://gta.wikia.com/Elegy_RH8) - 30*0 (on consoles) = 0
- Stealing Cars - 30*0 = 0
- [Karin Rebel](http://gta.wikia.com/Rebel) - 30*3,000 = 90,000

**Mods**
If you have Elegy RH8s you won't have to buy any mods and you are done.  If you steal cars or buy Rebels, then you'll have to mod every single car.  The cheapest mod I could find across cars that makes sure there's a cosmetic change was the Exhaust.  It seemed like the cheapest Exhaust mod was usually $750.

- Got Elegy RH8s - 30*0 = 0
- Modding cars with Exhaust - 30*750 - 22,500

**Total**
So assuming that you have no 10 car properties already and no cars, the absolute cheapest to get with 3 10 car garages and Elegy RH8s on consoles would be **337,500**.  This money would be completely spent on the garages.  The most expensive if you just buy 30 Karin Rebels, Exhausts, and get the cheapest 10 car apartment would be **530,000**.

Answer (score 1):

On the PS4, you cannot steal modded cars for it to count. Unlike in PS3.

**PS4** - The best way to do this is to buy Rebels, and many of them. Do a basic suspension, transmission (etc) overhaul. No need to change the paint, unless you want to.

**PS3** - On the PS3 you can actually steal modded cars and it will be counted. Although, it is a good idea if you add a cheap carbon spoiler on it or something, just to seal the deal. Apart from stealing, you can also buy Karin Rebels just like in PS4.

Hope it helped.